# Test Ads Showing But Real Ads Doesn't (Ad failed to load : 3)

Tags: android, admob

I am trying to learn AdMob integration in my android app. My code works fine for test ads unit ids but when I put my ad unit id then it shows the error **failed to load ad: 3**

Maybe I'm doing something wrong in getting Interstitial `Ad_Unit_id` from Admob?
Approximately 3 days ago, I had created Ad unit id from AdMob.

## MYCODE

```
package com.example.linechart;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.InitializationStatus;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.OnInitializationCompleteListener;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    LineChart chart;
    Button Month,Year,All;
    private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initialize the Mobile Ads SDK.
        MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
            }
        });
        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-5931392258417484/4357288114");
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial wasn't loaded yet.");
        }
        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                mInterstitialAd.show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                // Code to be executed when an ad request fails.
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdOpened() {
                // Code to be executed when the ad is displayed.
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClicked() {
                // Code to be executed when the user clicks on an ad.
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdLeftApplication() {
                // Code to be executed when the user has left the app.
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                // Code to be executed when the interstitial ad is closed.
            }
        });
    }
}
```

## MANIFIEST_FILE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.linechart">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-5931392258417484~9062819881"/>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got you. You don't have to wait for hours or days to get the Ad shown. The real thing is to just publish your app for once with the code you have. It is alright.
Now the point is **Why the app doesn't show ad?**

This is because AdMob wants to verify that your app is real and is generating impressions(here, the user interaction) that means your app is being used by people and generating ad requests.

When there are enough requests, the app will start to show real ads. There is no problem with waiting for hours. Just find ways of getting more ad requests.

Answer (score 0):

Normal, just wait a few hours.
Your implementation is fine.

Comment: I have waited 3 days :( it still showing me same error

Comment: Maybe is a issue with your admob account, have you tried another?

Comment: No i Dont have any other admob account